# My method SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync does not work when I login for only one user, which parameter is the correct one to send it?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am developing an application where a chat comes and this works with notifications, if I remove the "tag" it is sent to all the devices that have the application installed but I want to send it only to a user but I do not know what value is sent exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to send it only to a user

You need to send the message to the user's device registration token.

```
var messageJson = @"
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "some device token.........",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Welcome to StackOverflow",
      "title" : "Hello Marco",
      }
   }
}
";
SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(messageJson);
```

> To send to a single, specific device, pass the device's registration token

re: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: I did not work, because of the arrangement I need to send, I add the token parameter and keep sending them to everyone.

Comment: @MarcoGarcia Read the "Send messages to specific devices" section in the link in my answer... I know that that works and will only send to the device with that registered token. Also try using the Firebase console and sending a message to the device's token that you are using and look at the json payload of that message.

Comment: But is it with the token that is generated from Firebase?

Comment: It is the token that the device generated during registration

Answer (score 0):

There is a method SendDirectNotificationAsync
that accepts deviceHandle or array of deviceHandles to send messages directly to specific device.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.senddirectnotificationasync?view=azure-dotnet